# Pushing a xmm register into the stack without affecting flags

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64

Moving a xmm register to the stack can be done by

```
sub rsp,16
movdqu  xmmword [rsp], xmm0
```

Problem here is `sub add` modify rflags.

How can I achieve this without use of expensive `pushfq popfq`?

Comment: Use `lea rsp, [rsp-16]`.  That said, usually you would decrement the stack pointer before getting to the point where flags must be preserved to avoid this situation.

Comment: That is an actual answer to the question :)

Comment: Note that you can also use `lahf` and `sahf` to merely save the arithmetic flags in case a full `pushf`/`popf` combination is too expensive.